# wave 3d animation

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, animation

How to animate a 3D wave propagation similar to that in the following video ?

[enter link description here](https://blog.wolfram.com/2011/03/18/built-to-last-understanding-earthquake-engineering/)

Comment: Do you mean how to solve the time-dependent equations of the theory of elasticity in 3D?

Comment: Please add some more detail to your question! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes. How to solve the  time-dependent and animate it as 3D ?